# Prove isotropy from passive transformation method

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry

I want to show that space is isotropic when potential is given by $U = 4.5(x^2 + y^2)$ and I want to use the passive transformation method for that. Let's treat mass to be 1 for the object.

in $x,y$ frame, the equation of motion in $y$ direction is $\ddot y = -9y$ and solution to this ends up: $y(t) = c_1cos(3t)$

Now, in the rotated frame, by using the passive transformation, the ball's motion exactly ends up to be: $\ddot y' = -9y'$ . I calculated this by using the transformation of coordinates.

we know that: $y' = -xsin\theta + ycos\theta$ and for our example, let's check $\theta = 30$ degrees and let's say in $x,y$ frame, initial position of object at $t=0$ is $x=3, y=4$. What I end up with is:

$y(t) = 4cos(3t)$ 
$y'(0) = -3sin30 + 4cos30 = 1.96410161512$
$y'(t) = 1.96410161512cos(3t)$

It appears that $y(t)$ and $y'(t)$ don't seem isotropic at all as their behaviours/physics is definitely different. Then why do we say that potential $U = g(x^2 + y^2)$ is isotropic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In transformed coordinates:

$$ U(x', y')= g\big(
(x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta)^2 +
(-x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta)^2\big)$$

$$ U(x', y')= g\big(
(x^2\cos^2\theta + y^2\sin^2\theta + 2xy\cos\theta\sin\theta) +
(x^2\sin^2\theta + y^2\cos^2\theta -2xy\cos\theta\sin\theta)
\big)$$
$$ U(x', y')= g\big(
(x^2\cos^2\theta + x^2\sin^2\theta) +
(y^2\sin^2\theta + y^2\cos^2\theta)
\big)$$

$$ U(x', y')= g\big(
x^2 + y^2
\big) = U(x, y)$$

so...it does not depend on choice of coordinates.